# Redirects page speed issue

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, web, opencart, pagespeed

I've tried to force WWW on all site which worked well but when I am doing a page speed test, I am getting the following recommendation (for example):

```
Remove the following redirect chain if possible:

http://swing-and-play.com/catalog/view/theme/shopzone/image/social/facebook500.png
http://www.swing-and-play.com/catalog/view/theme/shopzone/image/social/facebook500.png
```

This is my htaccess:

```
# 1.To use URL Alias you need to be running apache with mod_rewrite enabled. 

# 2. In your opencart directory rename htaccess.txt to .htaccess.

# For any support issues please visit: http://www.opencart.com

Options +FollowSymlinks

# Prevent Directoy listing 
Options -Indexes

# Prevent Direct Access to files
<FilesMatch "\.(tpl|ini|log)">
 Order deny,allow
 Deny from all
</FilesMatch>

# SEO URL Settings
RewriteEngine On
# If your opencart installation does not run on the main web folder make sure you folder it does run in ie. / becomes /shop/ 

### Tomas Changes

#RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}  ^$
#RewriteRule ^product_id=30$ http://nerdtshirtsuk.com/index.php?route=checkout/cart [R=301,NE,NC,L]
#RewriteRule ^index.php?route=product/product&path=17&product_id=30$ /contact_us\.html [R=301,L]
#RewriteRule ^route=product/product&path=17&product_id=30$ http://swing-and-play.com/ [R=301,L]
#Redirect 301 /index.php?route=product/product&path=17&product_id=30 http://swing-and-play.com/
#RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
#RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
#RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
#RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
#RewriteCond %{http_host} ^swing-and-play.com [nc]
#RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.swing-and-play.com/$1 [r=301,nc]


### Tomas Changes End


RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^sitemap.xml$ index.php?route=feed/google_sitemap [L]
RewriteRule ^googlebase.xml$ index.php?route=feed/google_base [L]
RewriteRule ^download/(.*) /index.php?route=error/not_found [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !.*\.(ico|gif|jpg|jpeg|png|js|css)
RewriteRule ^([^?]*) index.php?_route_=$1 [L,QSA] 

RewriteCond %{http_host} ^swing-and-play.com [nc]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.swing-and-play.com/$1 [r=301,nc]




### Additional Settings that may need to be enabled for some servers 
### Uncomment the commands by removing the # sign in front of it.
### If you get an "Internal Server Error 500" after enabling any of the following settings, restore the # as this means your host doesn't allow that.

# 1. If your cart only allows you to add one item at a time, it is possible register_globals is on. This may work to disable it:
# php_flag register_globals off

# 2. If your cart has magic quotes enabled, This may work to disable it:
# php_flag magic_quotes_gpc Off

# 3. Set max upload file size. Most hosts will limit this and not allow it to be overridden but you can try
# php_value upload_max_filesize 999M

# 4. set max post size. uncomment this line if you have a lot of product options or are getting errors where forms are not saving all fields
# php_value post_max_size 999M

# 5. set max time script can take. uncomment this line if you have a lot of product options or are getting errors where forms are not saving all fields
# php_value max_execution_time 200

# 6. set max time for input to be recieved. Uncomment this line if you have a lot of product options or are getting errors where forms are not saving all fields
# php_value max_input_time 200

# 7. disable open_basedir limitations
# php_admin_value open_basedir none

<IfModule mod_expires.c>

    ExpiresActive on
    ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 month"

  # CSS
    ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 1 year"

  # Data interchange
    ExpiresByType application/json "access plus 0 seconds"
    ExpiresByType application/ld+json "access plus 0 seconds"
    ExpiresByType application/xml "access plus 0 seconds"
    ExpiresByType text/xml "access plus 0 seconds"

  # Favicon (cannot be renamed!) and cursor images
    ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access plus 1 week"

  # HTML components (HTCs)
    ExpiresByType text/x-component "access plus 1 month"

  # HTML
    ExpiresByType text/html "access plus 0 seconds"

  # JavaScript
    ExpiresByType application/javascript "access plus 1 year"

  # Manifest files
    ExpiresByType application/x-web-app-manifest+json "access plus 0 seconds"
    ExpiresByType text/cache-manifest "access plus 0 seconds"

  # Media
    ExpiresByType audio/ogg "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType video/mp4 "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType video/ogg "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType video/webm "access plus 1 month"

  # Web feeds
    ExpiresByType application/atom+xml "access plus 1 hour"
    ExpiresByType application/rss+xml "access plus 1 hour"

  # Web fonts
    ExpiresByType application/font-woff "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType application/vnd.ms-fontobject "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType application/x-font-ttf "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType font/opentype "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType image/svg+xml "access plus 1 month"

</IfModule>

# compress text, HTML, JavaScript, CSS, and XML
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/plain
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xhtml+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/rss+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/javascript
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-javascript

# remove browser bugs
BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4 gzip-only-text/html
BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4\.0[678] no-gzip
BrowserMatch \bMSIE !no-gzip !gzip-only-text/html
Header append Vary User-Agent
```

Can you please help me to find what's wrong in here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That error indicates that you're linking to the image without www., and thus the request is being redirected.

Find the reference in your HTML that is pointing at `http://swing-and-play.com/catalog/view/theme/shopzone/image/social/facebook500.png` and fix it.